# error TS2322: Type '() => string' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular 6. With the following code:

```
export class DateComponent implements OnInit {

  currentDate: string = new Date().toDateString;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

I am getting the following error, but I do not know what may be causing it.

> error TS2322: Type '() => string' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Answer (score 4):

You should invoke the function, not assign the function object. Adding `()` at the end should fix it

```
currentDate: string = new Date().toDateString();
```