# Getting (TS) Type '() => string' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: typescript

I am getting the following error and I cannot work out why its complaining..

> Error TS2322  (TS) Type '() => string' is not assignable to type
>   'string'.

Closest I came to finding info about this error was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54951404/error-ts2322-type-string-is-not-assignable-to-type-string) but while the error was the same the situation was not.

I am equating "cssClasses", which is defined as a string, to an anonymous function that returns a string.. That's the idea and the function returns a string yet its saying "string is not assignable to string"

How do I fix this?

This is my code:

```
        for (let day = 0; day < numberOfDays; day++) {

        cssClasses = (): string => {

            if (day == calendarLayout.dayDifference) {
                return "cal-heading2-day-" + day.toString() + " " + cssToday;
            } else
                return ("cal-heading2-date-" + day.toString())
        }...
```

Comment: A function is not a string. So you can't assign a function to a variable of type string. That's what the error is telling you. You can *call* the function and assign the string it *returns* to the variable, if that's what you want to do. But I don't really see the point of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct typing for your function is the following:

```
const cssClasses: () => string = () => {
    if (day == calendarLayout.dayDifference) {
        return "cal-heading2-day-" + day.toString() + " " + cssToday;
    } else {
        return ("cal-heading2-date-" + day.toString());
    }
}
```

As correctly pointed out in the comments, you are trying to assign the type `string` to a `function` that is returning a string, which is quite different.