# Type '() => string' is not assignable to type 'string' Typescript React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have seen this question a lot but none of the answers really work for me. Closest answer was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55701975/getting-ts-type-string-is-not-assignable-to-type-string) but that also doesn't work.

I have Tsx code like this

```
<img src={getLogo} alt="Airline Logo" />
```

and the function

```
const getLogo: string = () => {
  return "";
};
```

I get the error *Type '() => string' is not assignable to type 'string'* I don't know how to fix that. Common answer was to type the function something like this.

```
const getLogo:() => string = () => {
  return "";
};
```

then call the function like this

```
<img src={getLogo()} alt="Airline Logo" />
```

But whilst this works react doesn't really like when you do that and then it forces me to use an anonymous function like this

```
<img src={() => getLogo()} alt="Airline Logo" />
```

Which returns the original problem

```
'() => string' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

Comment: In what way does react not "like it when you do that"? That is the correct way. Please include the full warning.

Comment: The `src` attribute only accept strings, not functions. The function invocation is the correct implementation, `src={getLogo()}`.

Comment: Error is due because `getLogo` is the reference to a function returning a string. Try to put the return in to a variable: `const myLogo = getLogo()`

Comment: Thats just a roundabout way of doing src={getLogo()}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be like this

```
const getLogo = (): string => {
  return "";
};
```